# Best way to align itemize list with paragraph indents of the main text

Tags: horizontal-alignment, enumitem, mdframed

I am using the [`mdframed`](https://ctan.org/pkg/mdframed?lang=en) package to frame important results in a box. Within the box, I have an itemized list. I would like to reduce the indentation of the itemized list so that the bullets align with the paragraph indents of the main (body) text. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mdframed}
\global\mdfdefinestyle{mymdstyle}{%
  linewidth=1pt%
}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{mdframed}[style=mymdstyle]
    \begin{itemize}
      \small%
      \item{apple}
      \item{orange}
      \item{pear}
    \end{itemize}
  \end{mdframed}
  \caption{Figure caption}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

[image: itemize]

In the above image, the dashed line is where I would like the bullets to align.

What is the best way to reduce the indentation of the itemized list? In the [`enumitem`](https://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package, there are many different indentation/margin adjustment techniques. Which do I use?

Answer (score 1):

Set labelindent and leftmargin:

```
\setlist{labelindent=\parindent, leftmargin=*}
```

[image]

You can find more on this topic in the [enumitem manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf) on page 8 follwing.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mdframed}
\global\mdfdefinestyle{mymdstyle}{%
  linewidth=1pt%
}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{mdframed}[style=mymdstyle, innerleftmargin=-1.6pt]
    \begin{itemize}[labelwidth=\parindent]
      \small%
      \item{apple}
      \item{orange}
      \item{pear}
    \end{itemize}
  \end{mdframed}
  \caption{Figure caption}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

[image]