# Use the enumitem package to align enumerate labels with the paragraph indent

Tags: enumitem

I have the following MWE, which defines `itemize` environments within an `enumerate` environment:

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{book}

\usepackage[semibold,tt=false]{libertine}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\global\mdfdefinestyle{mymdframe}{%
  linewidth=1pt%
}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}[style=mymdframe]
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*),labelindent=\parindent,leftmargin=*]
  \item{\textbf{fruits:}}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item{apple}
      \item{orange}
    \end{itemize}
  \item{\textbf{vegetables:}}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item{cucumber}
      \item{eggplant}
    \end{itemize}
\end{enumerate}
\end{mdframed}

\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

I would like to align the (a) and (b) `enumerate` labels with the paragraph indent of the main text. How do I do this?

[This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/570745/15622) suggests using `labelindent=\parindent,leftmargin=*` with the [`enumitem`](https://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem?lang=en) package, but I tried to this in my MWE, but it didn't seem to work. What have I done wrong?

Comment: Remove the `labelindent=\parindent` from your list definition.

Comment: Also, unless you're a big-time fan of code clutter, please remove the pointless pairs of curly braces after `\item` statement. E.g., please replace `\item{\textbf{fruits:}}` with `\item textbf{fruits:}`, please replace `\item{apple}` with `\item apple`, etc. None of the `\item` directives take a formal argument.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't take into account the value of `innerparsep` (default: 10pt) in the `mdframed` environment, nor the frame line thickness. This code, though not quite perfect, is better:

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand{\ShowFrameLinethickness}{0.4pt}
\usepackage[semibold,tt=false]{libertine}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\global\mdfdefinestyle{mymdframe}{%
  linewidth=1pt%
}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}[style=mymdframe]
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*),labelindent=\dimexpr\parindent-11pt, align=left, leftmargin=*]
  \item \textbf{fruits:}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item apple 
      \item orange 
    \end{itemize}
  \item \textbf{vegetables:} 
    \begin{itemize}
      \item cucumber 
      \item eggplant 
    \end{itemize}
\end{enumerate}
\end{mdframed}

\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

[image]